# Use a public attribute in a static method on c#

Tags: c#

I created a plugin and I'm trying to use it on a class, the problem is that the method I'm trying to use in this class is a static method.

The struct of the plugin implementation is this:

[image: Plugin use struct]

The problem is in the method called `TestMethod`, on the `TestClass` class.
I can't use the attribute `TestPlugin` because it is not a static property.

I've tried to use it as static, but when I change this the `TestPlugin` property becomes `null`.
For this reason I tried to find a way to use it as a normal property, but after a lot of search I had not been able to find a way to do it.

The code is as follows:

`TestPlugin` declaration:

```
[ImportMany]
public IEnumerable<ITestPlugin> TestPlugin{ get; private set;}
```

Use of `TestPlugin` attribute:

```
private static void TestMethod(){
    ...
    // Here Visual Studio says that :
    //An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'ToastPlugin'
    foreach(plugin in TestPlugin){
       //Plugin's use
    }
    ...
}
```

Edit:

Is there a way to use `TestPlugin` inside of `TestMethod` without declaring `TestPlugin` as static, for the reasons said before?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you had two different instances of `TestClass`, one with two plugins and one with one plugin, what would you expect `TestMethod` to do? (I'd also refer to `TestPlugin` as a property rather than an attribute - `ImportMany` is an example of an attribute here, in C# terminology.)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use TestPlugin inside of TestMethod without
>   declaring TestPlugin as static, for the reasons said before?

Quick answer is no.

Basically you have the following options:

1. Make `TestPlugin` static as well.
2. Make `TestMethod` not be static.
3. Make `TestMethod` take a reference to a `TestClass` object as a parameter.
4. Add a static collection of `IList<IEnumerable<ITestPlugin>>` and in the `get`/`set` methods of the `TestPlugin` add/remove the class from that new collection.

Which of those four you would choose depends upon exactly what you are trying to achieve.